# django signals module object has no attribute 'post_save'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to when "Salon" object created, create a "Vault" object

this is the **models.py**

```
from django.db import models,signals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Vault(models.Model):
    salon = models.ForeignKey(Salon,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, unique=False)
    cash = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Salon(models.Model):
    salon_ismi = models.CharField(max_length=25,unique=False)
    adres = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    ulke = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=False)
    sehir = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=False)
    kasa = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, unique=False)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)
        verbose_name_plural = "Salonlar"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.pk
    def __str__(self):
        return self.salon_ismi
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('kentyonetim_salon_detail', args=(self.pk,))

    def create_vault(self, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        """Create Vault Model for every new Salon Model."""
        if created:
            Vault.objects.create(salon=self.salon_ismi,)

signals.post_save.connect(Salon.create_vault, sender=Salon, weak=False,
                              dispatch_uid='models.create_Vault')
```

When I try to run the server, it gives me an error:

> AttributeError: module 'django.core.signals' has no attribute
>   'post_save'

Please help me out. Would be much appreciate. Thank you.

> Versions of Libraries: 
>  Django==2.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are importing signals incorrectly. Try this instead:

```
from django.db.models import signals
```